# Unix Shell Scripting-how can i remove particular characers inside a text file?

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed

I have an one text file. This file has 5 rows and 5 columns. All the columns are separated by "|" (symbol). In that 2nd column(content) length should be 7 characters.

If 2nd column length is more than 7 characters. Then,I want to remove those extra characters without opening that file.

**For example:**

```
cat file1
```

> ff|hahaha1|kjbsb|122344|jbjbnjuinnv|
>
> df|hadb123_udcvb|sbfuisdbvdkh|122344|jbjbnjuinnv|
>
> gf|harayhe_jnbsnjv|sdbvdkh|12234|jbjbnj|
>
> qq|kkksks2|datetag|7777|jbjbnj|
>
> jj|harisha|hagte|090900|hags|

For the above case 2nd and 3rd rows having 2nd column length is more than 7 characters. Now i want to remove those extra characters without open the input file using awk or sed command

I'm waiting for your responses guys.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help , better to add expected output for clarity and also https://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: You can't edit a file without opening it.

Comment: It is unclear precisely what your "without open the input file" requirement means. In order to read the input file, the file _must_ be opened. If you just don't want to _overwrite_ the input file, you can write to a temporary file instead (as in @TomFenech's answer below).

Comment: You are asking this question in a different form: `I have a solid box containing apples. I don't know how many apples it contains but I need to be able to tell if there's more than 7 apples and if so remove the extra, all without opening the box`. See the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Take a substring of length 7 from the second column with awk:

```
awk -F'|' -v OFS='|' '{ $2 = substr($2, 1, 7) }1' file
```

Now any strings longer than 7 characters will be made shorter. Any strings that were shorter will be left as they are.

The `1` at the end is the shortest *true* condition to trigger the default action, `{ print }`.

If you're happy with the changes, then you can overwrite the original file like this:

```
awk -F'|' -v OFS='|' '{ $2 = substr($2, 1, 7) }1' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

i.e. redirect to a temporary file and then overwrite the original.

Answer (score 0):

First try

```
sed 's/\(^[^|]*|[^|]\{7\}\)[^|]*/\1/' file1
```

What is happening here? We construct the command step-by-step:

```
# Replace something
sed 's/hadb123_udcvb/replaced/' file1
# Remember the matched string (will be used in a later command)
sed 's/\(hadb123_udcvb\)/replaced/' file1
# Replace a most 7 characters without a '|' (one time each line)
sed 's/\([^|]\{7\}\)/replaced/' file1
# Remove additional character until a '|'
sed 's/\([^|]\{7\}\)[^|]*/replaced/' file1
# Put back the string you remembered
sed 's/\([^|]\{7\}\)[^|]*/\1/' file1
# Extend teh matched string with Start-of-line (^), any-length first field, '|'
sed 's/\(^[^|]*|[^|]\{7\}\)[^|]*/\1/' file1
```

When this shows the desired output, you can add the option `-i` for changing the input file:

```
sed -i 's/\(^[^|]*|[^|]\{7\}\)[^|]*/\1/' file1
```